# Hyperledger fabric v1.4 certificate renewal gives peer.blocksprovider warning at peer

Tags: certificate, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, peer

**Entities:** Org1 with 2 peers(peer0 & peer1), 1 Orderer, 1 IntCA.
Both peers joining a single channel

> I won't be able to add files/logs or code, as it's not allowed to. Hope it's understood.

Network was initially build with peer0+CA+orderer and later peer1 was added into Org1.
Recently we renewed certificates before the expiry date. peer0 and peer1 allows transaction in, but peer1 also throws a warning/error

> [peer.blocksprovider] func1 -\u003e WARN 4c87\u001b[0m Encountered an
> error reading from deliver stream: rpc error: code = Canceled desc =
> context canceled channel=mobileid orderer-address=orderer.xyz.com

What could be the possibility for this error(peer.blocksprovider)? could there be a mistake in cert renewal? if yes, what part could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to disabling gossip protocol within an org. Both the peers were leaders in this case and peer1 failing to disseminate blocks to peer0.
Same is not the case with peer0, which makes me think back on this.

Still no idea why this issue triggered after certificate renewal.